# Can someone help identify this plant?

Tags: identification

[image]
Was given this plant but do not know what kind it is

Comment: It looks like some kind of "bulb" type plant that has been grown with too little light (amaryllis maybe?).  Is there a bulb under the soil? If not, I might also take a guess that it could be a light starved Sanseviera of some kind.  Thought it might help. Not much to go by.